# Android getting Namespace not specified error. when i try to upgrade Gralde version of project

Tags: java, android, flutter, gradle

When I want to upgrade the Android project to a higher Gradle version, I receive this error during compilation:

```
Namespace not specified. Please specify a namespace in the module's build.gradle file like so:

android {
    namespace 'com.example.namespace'
}
```

My confusion is that the namespace in the build.gradle file has already been defined, and it gives this error when upgrading to a higher version.

The content of the build.gradle file:

```xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/launcher_icon"
        android:label="xxxxxx">
        <activity
            ...
            
        </activity>
        
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

`build.gradle`

```
...
android {
    namespace "mysite.com.myproject"
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }

    ...
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "mysite.com.myproject"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

Sections defined for the buildscript:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.9.0'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
```

And finally, the distributionUrl section:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.0-all.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

Open android -> app -> src -> main -> `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Replace

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
```

With

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="mysite.com.myproject">
```